# C# - Change the filename of converted file based on the orginal filename

Tags: c#, excel

Hello this is what i want to do, i want the `.xls` name or converted file to name based on the original file name `.dbf`. Example i convert the `acct_code.dbf`, the excel filename should be `acct_code.xls`. I tried concat it but it didnt work. Can someone help me? how to do this?

[image]

here is the code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;



            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=" + Directory.GetParent(textBox1.Text).FullName;
            string ExcelFileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "converted_file.xls"; <--- here's the file name for excel file
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
            {
                var sql = "select * from " + Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text) + ";";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Error connecting database: " + ex.Message , "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    return;
                }
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    MessageBox.Show("Reading database...  ", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    MessageBox.Show("Completed.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }

                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    GenerateExcel(dt, ExcelFileName);
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string originalFile = @"c:\Users\DonyaNenita\Desktop\Copro\install\acct_code.DBF";
string newFile = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(originalFile) + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFile) + ".xls";
```

Comment: 'System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFile)' is the key. Thanks bro :)

Comment: Use System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryName,fileName) instead of directoryName+"\\"+fileName

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in the [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension(v=vs.110).aspx) class that will do this

```
string oldFile = @"C:\folder1\folder2\file.dbf";
string newFile = Path.ChangeExtension(oldfile, ".xls");
// newFile is now C:\folder1\folder2\file.xls
```

Answer (score 1):

If your renaming a file then try this:

```
System.IO.File.Move("oldfile.txt", "newfile.log");
```

But if you want a function to rename a file then use either:

```
public void RenameFile(string path, string name)
{
    System.IO.File.Move(Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath) + name + Path.GetExtension(filepath);
}
```

If you just want a new name then use this:

```
string NewFileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath) + "newfilename" + Path.GetExtension(filepath);
```

And again a function:

```
public string GetPathWithNewName(string path, string newname)
{
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(path) + newname + Path.GetExtension(path);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, OP just wants to generate the new file name

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `GetFileWithoutExtension` method:

```
string basename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("foo.DBF");
string newFile = string.Join(".", basename, "xls");
```

I wasn't sure if you were renaming or making a new file...